# Can I redownload Minecraft on a different after purchasing it on android?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering if I purchase Minecraft on device A, can I download it on device B, using the same Gmail, such that both device have Minecraft? As when I purchased it, it showed me a refund button, so I assumed that I can only be used per device and if I want to play on another device I would have to refund and re-purchase. Is my assumption true?

Comment: If this is not a hypothetical question, why don't you try downloading Minecraft PE on device B and see what happens?

Comment: I have no experience for this, because I got my game because of APKs or a friend of mine sends their copy to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you own multiple android devices signed in to the same Google account, you can play anything you have bought on that account (ie. Minecraft) on both devices separately without any issue.